# yum dependancy error - looking for the wrong version of php-mysql

Tags: linux, mysql, php, yum, mariadb

So I was trying to upgrade from MariaDB 5.5 to 10.0.  (which is essentially MySQL fork)
The installation instructions say to

```
yum remove mariadb-server mariadb-common mariadb-compat
```

then re-install the new version.... but the `yum remove` also removed

```
php-mysql
php-pear-MDB2-Driver-mysql
```

Now when I go to re-install `php-msyql` I get an error:

```
> yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * centosplus: mirror.vcu.edu
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * ius: mirror.symnds.com
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.29-3.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo = 5.3.29-3.w5 for package: php-mysql-5.3.29-3.w5.i386
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.i386 0:5.3.29-3.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.29-3.w5 for package: php-pdo-5.3.29-3.w5.i386
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.3.29-3.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 for package: php-common-5.3.29-3.w5.i386
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-common-5.3.29-3.w5.i386 (webtatic)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Why is it even asking to install php-common??? I already have it installed:

```
>yum list installed|grep php
php-pear-MDB2.noarch         2.5.0-0.9.b5.el6                   @epel           
php-php-gettext.noarch       1.0.11-3.el6                       @epel           
php53u.i686                  5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-cli.i686              5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-common.i686           5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-devel.i686            5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-gd.i686               5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-mbstring.i686         5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-mcrypt.i686           5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-pdo.i686              5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius            
php53u-pear.noarch           1:1.9.4-3.ius.centos6              @ius            
php53u-zts.i686              5.3.28-4.ius.centos6               @ius
```

And .... I already have libcurl installed!

```
>yum list installed|grep libcurl
libcurl.i686                 7.19.7-40.el6_6.3                  @updates        
libcurl-devel.i686           7.19.7-40.el6_6.3                  @updates
```

Google says that this version of libcurl includes libcurl.so.4 and not 3. I looked in my system and there is a symlink from 3 to 4:

```
>ll /usr/lib/libcurl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jan  1 02:00 /usr/lib/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Feb 16  2014 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jan  1 01:59 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 346084 Dec  7 23:50 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.1.1
```

I noticed that `libcurl.so.3` is pointing at a non-existant file, and updated it to point at 4.1.1... but still no luck.

*What should I do??*

It doesnt look like yum has a `skip dependancy check`, but I would have to use `RPM -nodeps` to do this. But people say bad things happen.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I solved this with `rpm --nodeps` ...

first downloaded all the rpms after searching for them on [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net)

```
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.6/os/i386/Packages/php-mysql-5.3.3-38.el6.i686.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.6/updates/i386/Packages/php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.i686.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.6/updates/i386/Packages/php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.i686.rpm
```

then I ran each of them with `rpm -iv` just to see what happened, ofcourse they all barked about missing depedancies... so I ran them with `rpm -vi --nodeps` and everything works now.